# Correctly write a class and use pthread with vlc library and c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, class, ubuntu, libvlc

My application (C++, WxWidgets, Ubuntu) have to play different mp3 files depending on user actions. At the moment, I use vlc library and I always call a new function to reproduce the audio file, but this requires too much code and I think it's not so professional.
Since I do not want to stop the flow of the application while the mp3 is playing, I use threads.

I tried to write a class for the mp3, but I think it is not correct since I get this error:

```
    /home/isola/Documents/Isola02/secondpanel.cpp:68:102: error: invalid use of void expression
  pthread_create(&thread, NULL, mp3->play_mp3("/home/user/Project/audio/scegli-rifiuto.mp3"), NULL);
```

This is the code of my class:

**rePlay.cpp**

```
#include "rePlay.h"
#include <vlc/vlc.h>

rePlay::rePlay()
{
    //ctor
}

rePlay::~rePlay()
{
    //dtor
}

void rePlay::play_mp3(const char* path){
  // load the vlc engine
    inst = libvlc_new(0, NULL);
    printf("apro il file %d\n", inst);
    // create a new item
    m = libvlc_media_new_path(inst, path);
    // create a media play playing environment
    mp = libvlc_media_player_new_from_media(m);
    // no need to keep the media now
    libvlc_media_release(m);
    // play the media_player
    libvlc_media_player_play(mp);
    printf("Done.\n");
}

void rePlay::stop_mp3(){
  // stop playing
    libvlc_media_player_stop(mp);
    // free the media_player
    libvlc_media_player_release(mp);
    libvlc_release(inst);
}
```

and the header **rePlay.h**

```
#ifndef REPLAY_H
#define REPLAY_H
#include <vlc/vlc.h>

class rePlay
{
    public:
        rePlay();
        virtual ~rePlay();
        void play_mp3(const char*);
        void stop_mp3();
    protected:
        libvlc_instance_t *inst;
        libvlc_media_player_t *mp;
        libvlc_media_t *m;
    private:
};

#endif // REPLAY_H
```

My idea is to call:

```
pthread_t thread;
rePlay *mp3;
```

mp3->new rePlay();
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, mp3->play_mp3("/home/user/Project/audio/scegli-rifiuto.mp3"), NULL);

by passing the path of the file each time I want to reproduce a mp3 and then to call:

```
pthread_create(&thread, NULL, mp3->stop_mp3, NULL);
```

when I want to stop it.

At the moment, I get this error from the compiler regarding the pthread_create, but I think there should be other problems since I do not know if the play_mp3() and stop_mp3() could work.

Can you help me, please?

**EDIT1:** the class works if I do not use pthread_create function

**EDIT2**: If I use  I get the same error:

```
std::thread first (mp3->play_mp3("/home/robodyne/Project/audio/scegli-rifiuto.mp3"));
```

error:

```
/home/isola/Documents/Isola02/secondpanel.cpp:85:85: error: invalid use of void expression
  std::thread first (mp3->play_mp3("/home/robodyne/Project/audio/scegli-rifiuto.mp3"));
```

**EDIT3:**
Why if I declare `rePlay *mp3_apertura_porta;` in another class named `firstpanel` as `public`, then I get this error:

```
 /home/isola/Documents/Isola02/firstpanel.cpp: In member function ‘void firstpanel::check_cf(wxTimerEvent&)’:
/home/isola/Documents/Isola02/firstpanel.cpp:160:44: error: capture of non-variable ‘firstpanel::mp3_apertura_porta’ 
         std::thread second = std::thread([&mp3_apertura_porta]() noexcept {
                                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/isola/Documents/Isola02/firstpanel.cpp:1:0:
/home/isola/Documents/Isola02/firstpanel.h:20:12: note: ‘rePlay* firstpanel::mp3_apertura_porta’ declared here
    rePlay *mp3_apertura_porta;
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/isola/Documents/Isola02/firstpanel.cpp: In lambda function:
/home/isola/Documents/Isola02/firstpanel.cpp:161:9: error: ‘this’ was not captured for this lambda function
         mp3_apertura_porta->play_mp3("/home/robodyne/Project/audio/scegli-rifiuto.mp3"); });
```

when I call

```
 rePlay *mp3_apertura_porta = new rePlay();
    std::thread first = std::thread([&mp3_apertura_porta]() noexcept {
            mp3_apertura_porta->play_mp3("/home/isola/Documents/Isola02/audio/errore-ripetere-la-strisciata.mp3"); });
            first.join();
```

in firstpanel.cpp ?

Comment: Have you tested the rePlay class without calling it as a thread?

Comment: Why use the Posix C library pthreads instead of the C++ standard library `<thread>`?

Comment: it works fine without the thread, even if I need to declare the variables libvlc_instance_t *inst; libvlc_media_player_t *mp; libvlc_media_t *m; inside the play_mp3() function. The problem is that in this way the stop_mp3() function won't work because that variables are not global. How can I fix this?

Comment: OK, now I solved the problem with variables, I call  mp3 = new rePlay(); before anything else and it works. Now, the problem is just with pthread.

Comment: @TedLyngmo if I use <thread> as I reported in my second edit in the main topic, I get the same error: invalid use of void expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax for starting the thread in **EDIT2** is incorrect. Here's one way to do it with a lambda:

```
std::thread first = std::thread([&mp3]() noexcept {
    try {
        mp3->play_mp3("/home/robodyne/Project/audio/scegli-rifiuto.mp3");
    } catch(...) {
    }
});

//...

first.join();
```

Another option you could use if you are not comfortable with lambdas is similar to what you would use with `pthreads`:

```
// run MP3::play_mp3 on object mp3

std::thread second(&MP3::play_mp3, mp3,
                   "/home/robodyne/Project/audio/scegli-rifiuto.mp3");

// ...

second.join();
```

Comment: If I use that notation, I get this error: terminate called without an active exception
Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: Did you do `first.join()` too? Does `mp3->play_mp3("/home/robodyne/Project/audio/scegli-rifiuto.mp3");` work if you don't do it in a thread?

Comment: it works, I had to change the configuration of my compiler. Can you explain me the syntax used, please? I'm very interested in this topic but I never found this kind of syntax.

Comment: [std::thread](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread)'s constructor (nr 3 in the link) takes a functor, like a [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) and runs it in a new thread. Both links explains it better than I could do in comments :-)

Comment: @MarcusBarnet Added an optional way of starting.

Comment: thank you again @Ted Lyngmo! just the last question: I'm having problems if I declare rePlay *mp3_apertura_porta; inside another class. I added EDIT3 in my first topic to explain. I can't understand why it happens!

Comment: Lambda's can capture variables in the local scope, but not class members. Instead of `[&mp3_apertura_porta]`, do `[this]` an then inside the lambda `this->mp3_apertura_porta ...`. But starting the thread should probably be done by a method in your `MP3` class, not an external class.

Comment: thank you for your support. It now compiles and works fine! However, if I try to call the  `stop() ` method from another class named secondpanel, in this way:   `firstpanel *ptr; ptr->mp3_apertura_porta->stop_mp3(); ` I get segmentation fault. Why this happen?

Comment: You are welcome. When you do threading you need synchronization. Check `std::mutex`, `std::condition_variable` and the misc. locks that exist. I'm sure you'll have questions about those later - but I think this particular question has been answered? If so, please accept it and ask a new question if you have problems with something.

Comment: @MarcusBarnet Also check the `libvlc` documentation. It seems it has locking features built-in that you could use. It's not safe to call functions on one instance from multiple threads without locking.

Comment: I opened a new question, i tried to use the mutex as you suggested but i still have the same error.